# Truffle console send ETH to smartContract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I want to send some ETH to smart contract address

```
Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.contribute("0x1e0c326f4f24b5e9f5d42d695f48983d0a72b240", {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],value:10});})
```

but I always get

```
truffle(development)> Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.contribute("0x1e0c326f4f24b5e9f5d42d695f48983d0a72b240", {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],value:10});})
TypeError: instance.contribute is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:61
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
truffle(development)> truffle(development)>
```

I am using last version of truffle, so version 4.x

Same problem with

```
Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.getElements.call();})
```

Updated

```
contract MyContract Common {

  function setMultisigWallet(address newMultisigWallet) public onlyOwner {
    multisigWallet = newMultisigWallet;
  }

  function() external payable {
    executeSale();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your smart-contract code? It seams that the contract is not deployed. Maybe you forgot to run `truffle migrate`?

Comment: In your last snippet you have a typo: last token should be `call` (you are missing one `l`)

Comment: sorry copy paste error. It is call()

Comment: @Robert Zaremba it was deployt. I use truffle migrate

Comment: @Robert Zaremba i have updated the question with smart contract

Comment: You don't seem to have a function named `contribute` in your contract so it's normal that it is not working.

Comment: How to use then payable method?

Answer (score 0):

Send a transaction directly to a contract via `instance.sendTransaction()`. This is promisified like all available contract instance functions, and has the same API as [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) but without the callback. The `to` value will be automatically filled in for you if not specified.